# List of the syntax highlighting color settings relevant to Javascript for Visual Studio 2017

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2017, syntax-highlighting

Where can I find a list of the syntax highlighting color settings for Visual Studio 2017 that are relevant to Javascript?

That is, I know that the "String", "Keyword", and "Number" color settings are used in C#, Javascript, VB, etc.  But what other settings are available to me?  My JS code is looking very monochromatic, and experimenting in the "Fonts and Colors" dialog--hitting "Ok" and closing the window every time to see if something changed--is just painful.

Comment: Why are you editing JS in VS2017?  I'd strongly suggest getting VSCode for that purpose.

Comment: Please share a screenshot.

Comment: A screenshot of what--a text editor window?  The "Fonts and Colors" settings window?

Answer (score -1):

You can see this [How to: Change Fonts and Colors in Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh923906.aspx)

Or you need to enabled [javascript service](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/comments/34109/view.html)

Comment: In my question, I clearly stated that I have been changing colors in the "Fonts and Colors" dialog.